# UIimage not displaying image for duplicate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, duplicates

I have a UImage view that opens and you can take a picture with it and view it in the uiimageview. But I added another image view and copied the code and now the image shows up the same image as the second one. I believe it may have something to do with the '[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];'

```
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)
picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Get the image and store it in the image view
    image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.personimgThumbNail.image = image;

}

- (void)imagePickerControllertwo:(UIImagePickerController *)
picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Get the image and store it in the image view
    imagetwo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image = imagetwo;

}
```

Just need a next step, been stuck on this one for quite a while.

Comment: I think your problem may be that you have two didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. If you have declared your class as a UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, and your delegate as self, it will only be calling the first method above. Put your logic to decide which picker was selected in this method, i.e. if (picker == picker1) etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but i still dont believe i understand how you are saying i should correct my error and what code i should implement to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one didFinish-Method. You have to differentiate between what to do inside the method itself. The method already gives you the UIImagePickerController, which is calling the method, so you just have to compare the pointers to it.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)
picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

     if(picker == self.pickerController1){
        // Get the image and store it in the image view
        image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        self.personimgThumbNail.image = image;
    }else if(picker == self.pickerController2){
        // Get the image and store it in the image view
        imagetwo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image = imagetwo;
    }
}
```

Edit: You have to have 2 properties defined in the .m file of your class

```
@property (strong) UIImagePickerController *pickerController1;
@property (strong) UIImagePickerController *pickerController2;
```

What you have to do now, when instantiating your image-picker is the following 
(code taken from the OPs comment under this answer)

```
- (IBAction)accessPhotoLibrary:(id)sender {
    if(!self.pickerController1){
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
        imagePicker.delegate = self; 
        self.pickerController1 = imagePicker;
    }
    [self presentViewController:self.pickerController1 animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: Hey man, it keeps saying ' Property picker not found on ViewController' How do i define it. In the .h or .m?

Comment: Depends on how you instantiate the UIImagePickerController. You just have to keep a reference on the picker you are displaying so that you can compare which one calls the method. If you're allocating the picker in your code, a property in the .m-file is what you want.

Comment: Would this be correct? It was not showing any images.
    if(picker == self.personimgThumbNail.image){
        // Get the image and store it in the image view
        image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        self.personimgThumbNail.image = image;
    }else if(picker == self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image){
        // Get the image and store it in the image view
        imagetwo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image = imagetwo;

Comment: it gives me an error whenever i add numbers to the picker without defining it here is how i open the uiimage view  - (IBAction)accessPhotoLibrary:(id)sender {// Create the image picker controller
 UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];// Set the image picker controller properties
 imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  
 imagePicker.delegate = self;
    // Display the image picker controller
 [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: Okay, appreciate it I will try it when I get home.